# Why is capybara looking for "Mozilla geckodriver" when I have specified "chromedriver"?

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

I have an Rspec setup with a spec support file for Capybara that looks like this:

```
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.always_include_port = true
  config.app_host = 'http://www.myteaspoon.pdev'
  config.default_max_wait_time = 5
end

Capybara.register_driver(:chrome_headless) do |app|
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(
    args: %w[headless disable-gpu no-sandbox]
  )

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :chrome,
    options: options
  )
end

Capybara.default_driver = :chrome_headless

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

However when I try to run some specs I get the following error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: Unable to find Mozilla geckodriver. Please download the server from
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and place it somewhere on your PATH.
More info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver.
from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@au/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:136:in `binary_path'
```

What might be wrong and how do I debug it?

I have installed chromedriver using: `brew cask install chromedriver`

And it seems to be in path:

```
$ chromedriver -v
ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.126 (d80a294506b4c9d18015e755cee48f953ddc3f2f-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#1024})
```

Comment: Do you have any environment variables that are changing any rspec configs?

Comment: Is that the full stack trace in the exception you posted?

Comment: No, I don't think so. The full stack trace is just pointing at the spec. I figured that somehow the `Capybara.current_driver #=> :selenium` So by force setting the `Capybara.current_driver=:chrome_headless` inside a `before :each, js: true do`, then specs were acting okay. I have searched everywhere in the codebase and in all gems. Nowhere is Capybara.current_driver set to :selenium - so it's odd...?

Comment: Is the `current_driver` setter performing some logic where it defaults to `:selenium` if you supply an invalid argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you require capybara/rspec a hook is installed that sets the current driver to the value of Capybara.javascript_driver for any tests with :js metadata - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rspec.rb#L23 -.  If you want all tests (with and without :js metadata) to use the same driver then you need to set `Capybara.default_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome_headless`